# What function should I use to fix my code?

Tags: python

I'm an amateur trying to code a simple troubleshooter in Python but I'm sure what function I need to use to stop this from happening... 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJsB1.png)

What should I do so the code doesnt continue running if the user inputs yes?

```
  TxtFile =open('Answers.txt')
lines=TxtFile.readlines()
import random
def askUser(question):
    answer = input(question + "?  ").lower()
    Split = answer.split()
    if any(word in Split for word in KW1):
        return False
    elif any(word in Split for word in KW2):
        return True
    else:
        print("Please answer yes or no.")
        askUser(question)

KW1=["didn't", "no",'nope','na'] #NO
KW2=["did","yes","yeah","ya","oui","si"] #YES
print (lines[0])

print("Nice to meet you, " + input("What is your name? "))
print("Welcome to my troubleshooter")
#This is the menu to make the user experience better
shooter=True
while shooter:
   print('\n\n1.Enter troubleshooter\n2.Exit\n\n')
   shooter=input('Press enter to continue: ')
   if shooter==('2'):
       print('Ok bye') 
       break



words = ('tablet', 'phone', 's7 edge')
while True:
    question = input('What type of device do you have?: ').lower()
    if any(word in question for word in words):
            print("Ok, we can help you")
            break                
    else:
            print("Either we dont support your device or your answer is too vague")

if askUser("Have you tried charging your phone"):
    print("It needs to personally examined by Apple")
else:
    if askUser("Is it unresponsive"):
        print (lines[0])         
    else:
        print ("Ok")
    if askUser("Are you using IOS 5.1 or lower"):
        print (lines[1])
    else:
        if askUser("Have you tried a hard reboot"):
            print (lines[2]) 
        else:
             if askUser("Is your device jailbroken"):
                 print (lines[3])
             else:
                  if askUser("Do you have a iPhone 5 or later"):
                      print (lines[4])
                  else:
                      print(lines[5])
             print ('Here is your case number, we have stored this on our system')         
             print (random.random())
```

Here is my code for reference.

Edit: Here is the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJsB1.png)

It should just end the code there but it doesnt. I'm not sure how I can fix it

Comment: Can you post your full code including the `askUser` function as well as the source where `lines[0]-[2]` are coming from?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Where is the error coming from? Can you point out the specific portion of your code? Additionally, your indentation looks like it needs to be fixed in some spots. Are you using both tabs and spaces to indent your code?

Comment: I posted my full code. I'm printing lines 0-2 from a txt file that consists of this You need to send your iPhone back to Apple.
In settings you need to update your software.
Unfortunately there is nothing more we can do and your device needs to be repaired.
Jailbreaking your iPhone is breach of warranty, Apple can no longer help you.
You will have to factory reset your phone.
Thank you for using Apple customer service, have a great day.
We're sorry this hasn't been resolved, we will allocate you a case number #

Comment: Ok I edited it again, I used tabs and spaces.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend moving the following:

```
   if askUser("Are you using IOS 5.1 or lower"):
        print (lines[1])
    else:
        if askUser("Have you tried a hard reboot"):
            print (lines[2]) 
        else:
            if askUser("Is your device jailbroken"):
                print (lines[3])
            else:
                if askUser("Do you have a iPhone 5 or later"):
                  print (lines[4])
              else:
                  print(lines[5])
              print ('Here is your case number, we have stored this on our system')         
              print (random.random())
```

into the else part of:

```
if askUser("Is it unresponsive"):
```

Hope this helps.